# Сориентировать по центру

Tags: html, css

Нужно сориентировать по центру большой блок, используя только css.

Пробовал Vertical-align и флоат + маригн авто - ничего не работает, padding-left и margin-left не подходят.

Comment: vertical-align вообще как-то странно работает. Вродь надо давать блоку display: table-cell; и тогда вертикал алигн, да вот только что-то у меня это через раз работает)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
width: 246px;
height: 324px;
left: 50%;
magin-left: -123px;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -162px;
position: absolute;
```

vertical-align создан для выравнивания инлайновых элементов.
Выравнивание по высоте резинового контента поддерживает только элементы с

```
display: table-cell;
```

...если кроссбраузерно.

Comment: помогло, спасибо

Comment: Чтобы принять ответ, можно нажать галочку слева

Comment: Таким способом, кстати, удобно создавать полностью отцентрованные сайты, создав див #center с width=height=1px и потом туда добавляя элементы, позиционированные margin'ами. В этом случае надо не забыть поставить overflow: show;, ибо IE.